# Table with CSS sprites as bg images won't display correctly on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, image, gallery

I've tried everything, but nothing seems to get me a consistent result...basically, I have an image grid of thumbnails that I set up in a table due to the fact that rowspan got me the effect that I needed very easily (it's set up like a grid, but some of the photos are double the size of others). It displays fine across every browser, but when it displays on the iphone, it's as if random images are chosen to show and in random positions, sometimes repeated, with no rhyme or reason...I thought it was just my cache or something, so i cleared it and tried it on other phones, but to no avail!

Anyway, the page is: [www.ivryaudio.com/index.html](http://www.ivryaudio.com/index.html).  Please! I beg your assistance. Here's a [link](http://www.ivryaudio.com/images/screenshot.jpg) to a screenshot of the problem as well.

Comment: I forgot to mention, the images are css sprites as hyperlinks with display block - it's quite a few images and I felt guilty about making too many http requests. I'm sure that has to be contributing to the root of the problem somehow??

Comment: The two links are now dead making the question unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after hours of searching for the answer to a problem that was pretty broad, I stumbled on [this site](http://teknocat.org/blog/computer-stuff/web-development/show/6/mobile-safari-background-image-scaling-quirk). Apparently, your sprite can't be over 1024x1024 or it starts repositioning incorrectly. Hopefully someone else who has this problem will find this answer quicker than i did :0